# Как считать из файла только числа

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно записать в файл студентов: имена и их оценки по 4 предметам, ну или же сразу написать все это в файле. 

С этим проблем нет, а далее нужно вписать в другой файл имена студентов, которые имеют оценки 4 и 5. 

Вот здесь проблема, не знаю, как это осуществить. 

Попробовал создать целочисленную переменную и решил попробовать передавать в нее значения(ожидал, что будут передаваться только числа, но прошел отладкой, понял, что не так). 

В общем как можно это сделать ? 

Есть вариант искать слово "оценки:", но может есть другой

```
bool foo(vector<int>& name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        if (name[i] < 3) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    // Фрагмент записи в файл решил не добавлять
    int x, sum = 0;
    vector<int> v;
    bool check;
    ifstream iname("read.txt");
    ofstream oname2("write2.txt");
    if (!iname.is_open()) {
        exit(0);
    }
    else {                        // Чтение
        while (!iname.eof()) { // Об этом фрагменте писал выше
            if (iname >> x) {
                v.push_back(x);
                sum++;
            }
            if (sum == 4) {
                check = foo(v);
                if (check) {
                //  oname2 << "Yes" << endl; // Это я проверял, работает или нет
                }
                sum = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    iname.close();
    oname2.close();
}
```

Comment: По условию вроде как не надо ничего читать из файла. Записывайте одновременно в два файла.

Comment: Опишите толком (можно привести пример текста) формат входного файла.

Comment: Например: Михеев А.В. (имя)  Оценки: 4 3 4 4; Константинов А.В. Оценки: 4 5 4 4 и  т.д. В итоге перенести имена тех, у кого только 4 и 5 (В нашем случае: Константинов А.В.)

Comment: Между `:` и первым числом всегда есть пробел? А список оценок всегда завершается `;`?

Comment: @avp Даже не могу сказать, до таких подробностей не уточнялось, это видимо уже на наш взгляд. Ну допустим, что и пробел и ' ; ' имеются всегда. А что было бы, если бы они стояли лишь местами ?

Comment: Эти символы четко отделяют числовую инфорацию от текста, в начале которого находится интересующее вас ФИО. Если бы они стояли лишь местами, то это усложнило бы анализ входных данных (для правильного ввода слндующей порции мог бы потребоваться шаг назад)

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил сам, только пришлось создавать записи: "имя", "оценки", а уже после, на следующей строке, писать данные, хотя можно было без этого, просто представил, как все будет выглядеть и, отталкиваясь от этого, писал :

```
bool foo(vector<int> &n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
        if (n[i] < 4) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int volume;
    cout << "Введите количество студентов: "; cin >> volume;
    vector<string> fio; // Вектор хранения тех, кто подходит
    vector<int> num;
    int first, second, third, fourth;
    string name;
    string str;
    string st; // имя студента
    bool mark = false;
    bool strn = false;
    ofstream oname("write.txt");
    oname << "List of students: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < volume; i++) {
        cout << "Введите имя студента " << i + 1 << ": "; cin >> name;
        oname << "Name is student: " << endl << name << endl;
        cout << "Введите все оценки студента: "; cin >> first >> second >> third >> fourth;
        oname << "Assessments: " << endl << first << " " << second << " " << third << " " << fourth <<  endl; // Запись оценок в файл
    }
    oname.close();

    bool check;
    int sum = 0;
    ifstream iname("write.txt");
    if (!iname.is_open()) {
        cout << "File for reading is not open!";
    }
    else {
        while (getline(iname, str)) {
            if (strn) {
                st = str; // Хранение имени студента
                strn = false;
            }
            if (str.find("Name") != string::npos) {
                strn = true;
            }
            if (str.find("Assessments:") != string::npos) {
                mark = true;
                while (sum != 4) {
                    int x;
                    iname >> x;
                    num.push_back(x);
                    sum++;
                    if (sum == 4) {
                        check = foo(num);
                    }
                }
                if (check) {
                    fio.push_back(st);
                }   
                sum = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    iname.close();

    ofstream readn("read.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < fio.size(); i++) {
        readn << fio[i] << endl;
    }
    readn.close();

}
```